# HAProxy doesn't keep-alive http connection

Tags: http, haproxy, keep-alive

I've switched on the `option http-keep-alive` in the defaults, as well as tried it in the frontend definition.

But the Response Headers in the browser never show up keep-alive, although its there in Request Headers of the browser. Using Chrome as a browser.

The backend for haproxy is an apache 2.4 + php-fpm. HAProxy ver 1.5.3

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that your assumption is that `haproxy` will add a

```
Connection: keep-alive
```

header. That is not the case. Instead, the `keep-alive` mode (`KAL`, [default in 1.5.x](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#option%20http-keep-alive)) will just refrain from closing connections or adding `Connection: close` headers.

Your configuration is probably fine. You can test keepalive using `nc` for example, or `ab -k`.

Answer (score 5):

@felix-frank is right.

To check if keep-alive is supported or not simply execute this command :

```
curl -Iv http://www.serverfault.com/ 2>&1 | grep -i 'connection #0'
```

Result (Keep-alive disabled) :

```
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Closing connection #0
```

Another test with keep-alive enabled :

```
curl -Iv http://www.google.com/ 2>&1 | grep -i 'connection #0'
```

Result ( Keep-alive enabled) :

```
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```